# Updating multiple values simply in Spring MVC / Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm currently setting up a Spring MVC / Hibernate application, which will store a database of people.

I have set it up using the following tutorial (comments removed):
http://krams915.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html

```
public void edit(Person person) {
  logger.debug("Editing existing person");
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Person existingPerson = (Person) session.get(Person.class, person.getId());
  existingPerson.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
  existingPerson.setLastName(existingPerson.getLastName());
  existingPerson.setMoney(existingPerson.getMoney());
  session.save(existingPerson);
}
```

Is there a way that I can update the whole person, without having to specify each updated field (e.g. **existingPerson.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());**)? I want to be able to easily add as many fields as necessary, as the project expands, without having to update this class each time.

In the comments, there was something which suggested **session.update(page);** would work, but this just throws an error (*a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session*).

Comment: Use `Person updatedAndPersistentPerson = session.merge(person)`.

Comment: I've tried this, and session.merge(person) seems to work fine, without the rest - is there any reason I shouldn't just do this?

Comment: The rest only consists in assigning the result of `session.merge(person)` to a variable. It's there to make you realize that, unlike `update()` and `persist()`, `merge()` returns something, which is the attached entity on which the state of the detached entity has been copied. If you want to do something else with the attached entity, make sure to use the result of the method, because the argument of the method stays unmodified and detached.

Answer (score 0):

How is Person parameter of the function getting created.? Since id is already present for that object, I assume it is fetched from database before function call.

So just a session.save(person) should work in that case.